# In the GitHub world, what is the container of repositories called?

Tags: github

What is the container of repositories called?  I can create one of these and then add 1 or more repositories to it.

I checked the GitHub glossary (link below) and it is not clear to me whether or not this is called an "Organization" or "Project".

https://help.github.com/articles/github-glossary/

Answer (score 0):

In the GitHub terminology, a repository belongs either to a user account, or to an organization account.

So the direct answer to your question is "organization".

For example, the repository https://github.com/vuejs/vue.git corresponds to the the `vuejs` organization that hosts the `vue` software (that actually corresponds to the Vue.js framework).

As an aside, I usually find myself speaking of a "project" as a synonymous of a Git repository. However, note that the "Projects" keyword mentioned in the GitHub page (cf. the screenshot below) actually refers to a set of [Kanban boards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_board).

[image]